# If selenium can't find an element do something

Tags: selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using maven and selenium for testing in java. I would like to know if there is a way to call a function every time a test fails. I already have a function that takes an screenshot of the browser. I would like to use it every time selenium throws NoSuchElNoSuchElementExeption for example.
Is there an "easy" way to implement this?
Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you implement exception handling and catch for the specific exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found this solution to the problem:

https://darrellgrainger.blogspot.com/2011/02/generating-screen-capture-on-exception.html?m=1

Consists on using WebDriverEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to find the element and implement a try-catch block inside that to catch the NoSuchElementException. Call your function to take the screenshot inside that catch block.
e.g.

```
public WebElement findElement(By locator) {
    try {
         WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
         return element;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException nse) {
         // call the function to take a screenshot
    }

}
```